# Stuck on sas code. Doing this for the first time R code in SAS

Tags: sas

I am trying to run some R code in SAS but I am getting a weird error: The RLANG system option must be specified in the SAS configuration file or on the SAS invocation command line to enable the
submission of R language statements.

Could I please get some assistance?

```
PROC IML;
 SUBMIT / R;
# Copy-paste the section below into the R command prompt, # but only after editing with the correct path to the input data file.
# Lines that begin with the # character are taken as comment lines by R.
# $PATH in the line below is your specific data file path in full
# $PATH specifies the location of the input data file, assumed to be named mydata.csv
# $PATH file path is constructed with \ in Windows and / in Linux, Mac
# input data file mydata.csv must be in CSV comma separated value format
mydata <- test.csv("$PATHC:\Users\Christos\Desktop\test.xlsx")
# define the logit model
mymodel <- default ~ student + balance + income
# invoke logit regression
mylogit <- glm(formula = mymodel, data = mydata, family = binomial(link="logit"))
# display results of logit regression
summary(mylogit)
ENDSUBMIT;
QUIT;
```

Thanks in adavanced!

Answer (score 2):

You have to tell SAS before it starts that you want to enable the integration with R.  That is what the [RLANG option](https://documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=pgmsascdc&cdcVersion=9.4_3.3&docsetId=imlug&docsetTarget=imlug_r_sect003.htm&locale=en) does.

> If you attempt to submit R statements on a system that was not
> launched with the -RLANG option, you get the following error message:
>
> ERROR: The RLANG system option must be specified in the SAS
> configuration file or on the SAS invocation command line to enable the
> submission of R language statements.
>
> Some operating systems do not support the RLANG system option. The
> RLANG system option is currently supported for the Windows and Linux
> operating systems. If you attempt to submit R statements on a host
> that does not support the RLANG option, you get the following warning
> message:
>
> WARNING: SAS option RLANG is not supported on this host.

If you are launching SAS from the command line just add the **-rlang** option to your command.  Otherwise add to one of the config files that SAS is using.  For example on Unix you could add it to the sasv9.cfg file in your home directory.  If you are using a workspace server (via SAS/Studio or Enterprise Guide for example) then you probably need to talk to your local SAS installation team to have that option added to the configuration file.

Comment: The "target field" of a shortcut is the command line.